# Problems with Java and Symlinks

Tags: java, symbolic-link

i'm having troubles with the java jar files symlink. First of all i've to use java -jar command if i don't do it the java file doesn't run properly.
Well the problem starts when i symlink the jar file, then even trying to use the command the symlink doesn't run in the terminal.
Could you help me?
If it's possible i don't want to make a .desktop file for running the symlink :P
Regards

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run `java -jar symlink.jar`?